# How to reference CefSharp inside Azure function?

Tags: c#, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, cefsharp.offscreen

I created two projects: the first is a typical HTTP triggered Azure function and the second is just a sample of CefSharp.MinimalExample.OffScreen app. Azure function references CefSharp proj for screenshot-making purposes. This referencing works perfect locally, but not in Azure.  After publishing Log streaming utility shows problem with loading assembly 'CefSharp.Core.DLL'

```
2019-04-26T19:09:57.132 [Info,Function1] Function started (Id=1824ad19-be9e-4fd1-a3a4-17e770967164)
2019-04-26T19:09:57.132 [Info,Function1] Executing 'Function1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=1824ad19-be9e-4fd1-a3a4-17e770967164)
2019-04-26T19:09:57.132 [Info,Function1] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2019-04-26T19:09:57.148 [Error] A ScriptHost error has occurred
2019-04-26T19:09:57.148 [Error] Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
2019-04-26T19:09:57.194 [Error,Function1] Exception while executing function: Function1
2019-04-26T19:09:57.194 [Error,Function1] Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
2019-04-26T19:09:57.194 [Error,Function1] Function completed (Failure, Id=1824ad19-be9e-4fd1-a3a4-17e770967164, Duration=73ms)
2019-04-26T19:09:57.210 [Error,Function1] Executed 'Function1' (Failed, Id=1824ad19-be9e-4fd1-a3a4-17e770967164)
2019-04-26T19:09:57.210 [Error,Function1] Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
2019-04-26T19:09:57.210 [Error,Function1] Function had errors. See Azure WebJobs SDK dashboard for details. Instance ID is '1824ad19-be9e-4fd1-a3a4-17e770967164'
2019-04-26T19:09:57.210 [Error,Function1] Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
2019-04-26T19:09:57.210 [Error] {"id":"42f419f5-9cc7-4c90-bd6b-92836626c25f","requestId":"213b53eb-ee2c-475e-8094-a9e2ebcb6665","statusCode":500,"errorCode":0,"message":"An error has occurred. For more information, please check the logs for error ID 42f419f5-9cc7-4c90-bd6b-92836626c25f"}
2019-04-26T19:09:57.210 [Error] Could not load file or assembly 'CefSharp.Core.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
2019-04-26T19:09:57.132 [Info] Function started (Id=1824ad19-be9e-4fd1-a3a4-17e770967164)
2019-04-26T19:09:57.132 [Info] C# HTTP trigger function processed a request.
2019-04-26T19:09:57.194 [Error] Function completed (Failure, Id=1824ad19-be9e-4fd1-a3a4-17e770967164, Duration=73ms)
```

My project structure and FTP dll's
[image]

- I used Release | x64 (net461) configuration for publishing because build failed for x86 (System.BadImageFormatException) bla, bla..
- I slightly modified nuget CefSharp.OffScreen.targets file and added **bin** folder as CefSharpTargetDir because half of assemblies were out of bin folder
- I checked kudu and ftp that D:\home\site\wwwroot\bin> contains all the  files needed cefsharp to start.

Its interesting that if Azure Webjob (AuthWebjob.csproj) references Cefsharp everything works ok!. Probably i miss something either in project structure or in app settings of Azure VM.

Comment: which version of azure function are you using ? v1 works for .net framework. v2 works for .net core

Comment: @Thomas AzureFunctionsVersion v1, TargetFramework net461, i think it is default Functure proj template for VS2017

Comment: Can you check on the azure portal that the app setting `FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION` = `~1` ?

Comment: @Thomas Yes, exactly what you says FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION = ~1, platform x64. If needed i can send you my solution to test.

Answer (score -1):

With CefSharp.Core being a native C++ library, you can try switching your function to V2 and copying the binaries to wwwroot\ folder via FTP. If that doesn't work, then I'm afraid it may not be supported yet. I came across github issues [here](https://github.com/Corey-M/NAudio.Lame/issues/20), [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1470), and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/1469) that point to its a feature that's been requested but not yet adopted.